# How to uninstall a particular dll from winetricks?

Tags: wine, winetricks

Have [Googled](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=install%20riched20%20dll%20winetricks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ESpgUte0LJGHrAfRvYCoCw#channel=fs&q=remove%20dll%20from%20winetricks) for this but couldn't find a way to re-install **riched20.dll** I installed to install a Windows application (I don't remember the application) some days ago.

Is there anyway(command-line or via the GUI) to remove and/or re-install dll's installed in winetricks?

Specifications:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- winetrics 20120912

Comment: Do you want to uninstall the DLL or install the DLL? I'm sure wine doesn't include DLL's.

Comment: I want to uninstall the riched20 DLL. You can install DLL's from winetricks.

Comment: I want to ask this, too.
It seems that the winetricks only provides the option to remove all *.dll, but not some particular ones.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following in winetricks when I loaded a DLL that broke a game:

1. Select the default wine prefix
2. Click *Change Settings*
3. Check the box `alldlls=default` then click `OK`
4. Reinstall DLLs as necessary

This got me back up and running.

Comment: Sorry but I don's have access to the system i was facing this problem on, I'll try if i replicate this issue. Thanks.

Comment: the dll's are still selected in the winetricks wineprefix and cannot be reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete from wine folder the `riched20.dll` then add again via winetricks.

```
rm ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/riched20.dll
```

Comment: Wrong. There are packets installed under `/usr/lib/` and other places as well. Removing that dll under wineprefix just disables the dll.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to at least disable a DLL. Open `winecfg` and go to Libraries. The DLLs installed by winetricks seem to have an asterisk (*) before their name, find the DLL you want to remove and change it to 'builtin' or remove it from the list.